# vxWorks 6.8 mapping physical to virtual memory

Tags: memory, mapping, memory-address, vxworks, memory-mapping

This is my first question here :).

I been trying for while now to map physical memory to virtual memory in vxWorks 6.8 with no success,
I'm trying to use "vmMap" function but somehow it keeps return with:

errno = 0x30065  S_taskLib_NAME_NOT_FOUND.

my code is:

```
int page_size=0;
PHYS_ADDR GPIO_BASE_VIRTUAL_ADDR = 0x40E00000;
VIRT_ADDR VIRTUAL_ADDR=0;

page_size =vmPageSizeGet();
if((VIRTUAL_ADDR = (VIRT_ADDR)memalign(page_size,page_size*2))==NULL)// allocate 2 pages 
{
    printf("error in memalign() errno = 0x%x\n",errnoGet());
}

if(vmMap(NULL,VIRTUAL_ADDR,GPIO_BASE_VIRTUAL_ADDR,(page_size*2))== ERROR )
{
    printf("Error mapping memory errno = 0x%x%\n",errnoGet());
}
```

Any help will be very appreciate,
thanks,

Moshe.

Comment: Did you figure this out yet?  Some vxWorks functions don't set errno when they fail, so you can set it to 0 before calling the function to check if the errno is really from vmMap.

Comment: Hi,
yes i solved it, 
the same way for both addresses (0x160... and 0x40E....)
in the syslib.c file in the BSP


 { /* MAP GPIO */
 (VIRT_ADDR) 0x40E00000,     /* virtual address */
 (PHYS_ADDR) 0x40E00000,     /* physical address */
 0x1000,      /* length, then initial state: */
 VM_STATE_MASK_VALID | VM_STATE_MASK_WRITABLE | VM_STATE_MASK_CACHEABLE ,
 VM_STATE_VALID      | VM_STATE_WRITABLE      | VM_STATE_CACHEABLE_NOT
 },




and virtual with the needed "allocation size" and,
used the pointer to the requested address as "flat" just as is with the needed offsets.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already solved this long ago, but thought I'd leave some bread crumbs for whoever else might stumble this way in the dim & distant future..

Unless you're doing RTPs there's a good chance your MMU isn't even translating addresses. I.e., if something appears at say, 0x7fc00400 in the physical address space, you could simply cast that value to a pointer and use it.

```
*((short *) 0x7fc00400) = foo; // write 16 bits!
```

And Yes, these days it is almost sacrilege to suggest (ab)using pointers this way, but I would point out that if you're doing vxworks kernel space code, you're practically on the bare metal anyway, so why not?